# Swipe gesture between view controllers

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode6, xcode-storyboard, swipe-gesture

I am trying to create a swipe on background. I have three different color of backgrounds. I have made a button and when I click my button my background changes to next scene. 
I want to change this and I want to swipe my thumb left or right to change the background and not to have to click on the button. How would I achieve that.

here are some more details

my view controller is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a question about Swift. You need to look into [`UIGestureRecognizer`s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html), a set of classes in the Cocoa Touch framework.

Comment: You should not be "going back" to the initial controller from the blue controller with a forward segue (only use an unwind for going backwards). You're not actually going back, you're creating a new instance of that initial controller.

Answer (score 7):

Swift version:

Add gesture recognizer:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeLeft:")
    recognizer.direction = .Left
    self.view .addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}
```

action function:

```
func swipeLeft(recognizer : UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MySegue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, So I figured it out. Xcode has swipe gesture in its right panel and it was as same as dropping the button in the view. Only difference is that it shows up on the top instead of inside the view. So after I figured that it was as easy as holding the ctrl button and dragging it to another view and voilla it worked. 
Below are some images for some people if they stumble upon this:

[image]

[image]